# Run a local command after closing an SSH connection?

Tags: linux, command-line, zsh

I've set up my `zsh` to [update the XTerm title whenever I change directories](http://www.refining-linux.org/archives/42/ZSH-Gem-8-Hook-function-chpwd/).  It's neat!  Unfortunately I have one common problem, which is this:

```
% cd foo;       # title changes to "host1:~/foo"
% ssh host2;    # title changes to "host2:~"
% pwd
/home/user/foo  # title is still "host2:~"
```

I need to run some command anytime an ssh connection terminates, either `chpwd`, or `cd .`, or something similar.  I don't think I can use an alias, because I'd need something like

```
alias ssh=ssh $*; cd .
```

but AFAICT [you can't pick where the arguments go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/941338/shell-script-how-to-pass-command-line-arguments-to-an-unix-alias/941384#941384) in an alias.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, a comment: In `zsh` (and btw. also in `bash` & friends) you cannot use arguments in an alias. Use a function instead:

```
# function hello() { echo $1 $3 } 
# hello one two three
one three
```

You change the title in the `chpwd()` function, which is called whenever you change the directory. So, you need to use `cd .` to update your title. Or -- following your approach -- ,,overload'' the `ssh` command with this function to execute `chpwd()` after the ssh session ends:

```
function ssh() { command ssh "$@"; chpwd }
```

---

A solution I prefer is to place the command to change the title in `precmd()` which is executed before the prompt gets displayed. I define for example in my `~/.zshrc`

```
precmd () {
   [[ -t 1 ]] && print -Pn "\e]0;%n@%m:%~\a"
}
```

to get a title like `user@host:/current/dir`, which updates immediately when connecting to a remote machine (provided, there is a similar code in the `~/.zshrc`) and when returning to the local session.

(The `[[ -t 1 ]]`  checks, if the session is connected to a terminal -- it's not that important.)

Comment: This does fix the problem, but it seems like overkill -- this runs the command not only on directory change but before every command, even if the PWD hasn't changed.  I was hoping to run it only after finishing an SSH session, because I don't change the XTerm title anywhere else...

Comment: @JamesB : I don't bother about this <10ms overhead, but I edited my answer accordingly to pick up your approach, too.